# Google Calendar JSON feed to TableView

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, calendar, tableview

I currently have a JSON feed from a google calendar which can be found [here](http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json)

I have managed to get the event title and `startDate` into a table view. My only problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to group the events by date.

So for example, I have 3 events tomorrow.

- 10 am - doctor appointment
- 3 pm - soccer
- 9 pm - John's party

Currently I have those three events in a table view each with a separate cell. I'm trying to get them in a grouped table view with tomorrows date as the header. 
I have a custom object that has `NSString` and an `NSArray`. I use the following code currently to set my object.

```
NSMutableArray *objectArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I enumerate my `jsonDictionary`

```
[objectArray addObject:[event setTitle:[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"] objectForKey:@"entry"] objectAtIndex:idx] objectForKey:@"title"] valueForKey:@"$t"] withEvent:[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"] objectForKey:@"entry"] objectAtIndex:idx] objectForKey:@"gd$when"]  objectAtIndex:0]]];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Create an NSMutableArray that contains an object for each date.  That object can be a custom object, or an NSMutableDictionary which contains the date value and an NSMutableArray of all the events for that date.  Each event is also represented by a custom object or an NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

If you make your model right, the table view will follow naturally.  Seems like the appropriate model is an array of Day objects.  Each would have a date and an array of events.  Then your number of sections answers

```
return self.days.count;
```

And your number of rows in section answers

```
DayObject *day = self.days[section];
return day.events.count;
```

And an event at an index path is:

```
EventObject *event = self.days[indexPath.section].events[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's my model that's screwing me up. Please see updated question to how I set my model